# Spring MVC Apache tiles: footer is missing from output

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am now in Spring mvc trying to learn apche tiles...but its not working....don't know why?

****servlet-context.xml** file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">




<mvc:annotation-driven />



<bean   
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.
     InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mymvc.myapp" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
< /bean>


</beans>
```

**Tiles dependicies in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**general.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
  <tiles-definitions>
   <definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/layout/classic.jsp">
     <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
 </definition>

  <definition name="index" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Java Blog Aggregator" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
 </definition>
 </tiles-definitions>
```

**classic.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title><tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title>
 </head>
  <body>
     <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
     <br>
     <br>
     <center>
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
     </center>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**footer.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

   &copy;IShmam Shahriar
```

**IndexController.java**

```
package com.mymvc.myapp;

 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

 @Controller
 public class IndexController {
      @RequestMapping("/index")
       public String index(){
           return "index";
       }
  }
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO- 
      8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <p>index page</p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: "but its not working" - what does this mean exactly?

Comment: I expect  output ....index page with a footer..... index page is being shown....but footer is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong! It has a closing `<body>` and `<html>` tag in you "main-content (`index.jsp`)"!

You have your template: `classic.jsp` and you include `index.jsp` in the `<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />` placeholder. So the resulting HTML would looks like, (the complete `index.jsp` will be inserted at the placeholder!):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>...</title>
   </head>
   <body>
<html>                            <!-- problem starts her -->
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <p>index page</p>
   </body>                        <!-- that is the reason for not -->
 </html>                          <!-- having a footer -->
         <br>
        <br>
         <center>
            &copy;IShmam Shahriar
         </center>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Did you noticed that you "close" the html content with `</body>` and `</html>` already before the footer! -- The solution is simple: remove all the header, html and body tags from `index.jsp`:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

   <p>index page</p>
```

---

An other point:

Remove your `InternalResourceViewResolver` from the configuration. The problem is that you have two view resolvers (Internal and Url/Tiles) and it is likely that your viewname (`return "index"`) is resolved by the Internal view resolver, but not by the Url/Tiles resolver.

According to [Spring Reference, Chapter 18.3.2 Integration Tiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles-integrate), you just need:

- `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer`
- `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver` with `TilesView` configured for `viewClass` property (or use `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver` - that is an anready configured subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver`)

  - and you can have a `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver`

example:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
   <property name="definitions">
       <list>
           <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```